# Select unique lines from result table

Tags: sql

I have a self join result table which I have a lot of duplicated lines (because I have history on that table as well..).
the result table is (date, date, varchar, int, int, int, int).
how can I return only unique lines (where all of the columns identical..)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT`

```
select distinct * 
from yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by unique; given a table:

```
create table example
(
    col1 int
    ,col2 int
)
insert example (col1,col2) values (1,2)
insert example (col1,col2) values (1,2)
insert example (col1,col2) values (1,3)
insert example (col1,col2) values (1,4)
```

Would you want the result to be:

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
```

(i.e. the returned rows are unique; though there may be multiple rows with these same values in the source table)

or:

```
1,3
1,4
```

(i.e. you only want those rows which were unique in the source data to begin with)

If the former, use:

```
select distinct col1
, col2 
from example
```

If the latter, use:

```
select col1
, col2 
from example
group by col1
, col2
having count(1) = 1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/594ac/1